How Can I Achieve a Zoom-Out Effect for a Website When the Viewport Width is Below 190px?
I’m trying to replicate a zoom-out effect similar to what’s seen on SuperSimpleDev's Amazon Clone when the viewport width goes below 190px. I have a video showcasing the exact effect I want to achieve, which you can view here: Video The video contains the exact same CSS and HTML as the source website for the header.
I’ve tried the following approaches to achieve this effect:
CSS Media Queries: Applied transform: scale() for scaling content, but it didn’t produce the desired zoom-out effect.
@media screen and (max-width: 190px) {
  body {
    transform: scale(0.5); /* Tried different values */
    transform-origin: top left; /* Tried different values */
  }
}


Viewport Meta Tags: Adjusted viewport settings in the meta tag to control initial scale and width.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


JavaScript: Experimented with JavaScript to dynamically scale content based on viewport width, but did not get the expected result.
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 190) {
    document.body.style.transform = 'scale(0.5)';  /* Tried different values */
    document.body.style.transformOrigin = 'top left'; /* Tried different values */
  } else {
    document.body.style.transform = 'none';
  }
});


I’m checking my code through the VS Code Live Server extension, and my website is not actually hosted anywhere. Despite these efforts, I’ve noticed that the source of the referenced website doesn’t include any media queries, CSS rules, or JavaScript directly controlling the scaling effect. I’m wondering if this behavior might be related to the browser’s default zoom or scaling features when the viewport becomes very small.
Here’s what I’m looking for:
-How can I achieve a zoom-out effect similar to the one on the referenced site?
-Is this behavior likely related to browser default scaling or zoom features?
-Are there specific browser settings or default behaviors that might influence this effect?
Any insights or suggestions on how to replicate or understand this effect would be greatly appreciated!

I think this is a Chrome feature. The website doesn't do this in Firefox, and I tested one of my own websites, in which I definitely didn't include this feature, and it does it too, but only in Chrome.
